# Code breaks when page demoted to subsite

Tags: 2013, javascript, development

I have a group of related lists that were originally implemented at the site collection level, but are now so numerous that I'd like to move them to their own subsite. I have imported the lists to the new site fine, but the page that pulls all of the information together for display, now throws the ever helpful "Something went wrong...file not found" error.

I have a feeling that the problem is with the beginning section here:

```
<script runat="server">
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args){ 
        if(!Page.IsPostBack){
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
                      delegate{ 
                                using (SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb()){                    
                                    searchin.InnerHtml = "";
                                    SPList list1 = oWebsite.Lists["oncallcalendarlist"];
                                    SPQuery query1 = new SPQuery(); 
                                    query1.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy>";
                                    SPListItemCollection items1 = list1.GetItems(query1);
                                    String ItemName;
                                    ...
```

Please keep in mind that I didn't code the original page (though I have changed and expanded it's functionality many times), and I'm learning on the fly :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you look in the ULS log for the correlation ID? How did you do the import? Could some of the internal column names have changed?

Comment: I exported the list via Central Admin and imported to the new subsite via powershell. The list shows perfectly in the new subsite with all data and the column names are unchanged.

Thanks so much for the simple tip of looking at the logs though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigating the ULS logs, had me look at the path to the Master Page that the current page was using.

Problem turned out to be that my page was looking for the Master Page at it's own level, when it should have gone to the one above.

Changed the file path and it worked like a charm!